# How to create two text tags with different alignments in a single row using React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native, tags

In this example i tried to display two different things inside a listitem.

The problem is i couldn't manage to find out how can i show the **"item.date"** on the left of the line and **"Click to show."** string on the right of the line.

[Solution with spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntnWK.png)

The code sample of the image is below:

```
<Text style={styles.textline}>{"\n"+item.date}<Text style={styles.continuetext}>{Array(22).fill('\t').join('')}Click to show.</Text></Text>
```

I have managed to do it by adding multiple "\t" to the string but its a bad solution and it can change according to screen size.

And i have already tried to wrap the two text tags inside a view tag and gave the prop "flex:1" to the view tag, then gave the text tag prop "alignSelf: "flex-end" " didn't work either.

Edit: I have tried to wrap texts inside a view like mentioned in the comments didn't work.

Full code here:

```
 return( <ListItem thumbnail key={i}>
    <Thumbnail square source={{ uri: 'url' }} />
  <Body>
    <TouchableScale transparent onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL(item.url)}} 
      Component={TouchableScale}
      friction={90} 
      tension={100} 
      activeScale={0.95}>
    
      <Text>{item.head+"\n"}</Text>
      <Text note numberOfLines={2}>{item.details}</Text>
      <View style={{ flex:1,justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize:12,color: 'gray'}}>{"\n"+item.date}</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize:12,color: '#143f90'}}>Click to show.</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableScale>
  </Body>
</ListItem>);
```

I am kinda new to React Native, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Text>{item.date}</Text>
  <Text>Click to show</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: With flex:1 prop, one list item uses all the space in container, and when i remove it,  texts are aligned  to left and right as i wanted and everything is ok but they are not on the same line. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please update your example then, we might need more context to your issue

Comment: And my tag hierarchy is like : Container->Content->List->listItem->TouchableOpacity->this